# 'At' symbol before variable name in PHP: @$_POST

Tags: php, error-handling, operators

I've seen function calls preceded with an at symbol to switch off warnings. Today I was skimming some code and found this:

```
$hn = @$_POST['hn'];
```

What good will it do here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: @ is also know as an atpersand.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The `@` is the error suppression operator in PHP.

> PHP supports one error control
>   operator: the at sign (@). When
>   prepended to an expression in PHP, any
>   error messages that might be generated
>   by that expression will be ignored.

**See:**

- [Error Control Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)
- [Bad uses of the @ operator](http://michelf.com/weblog/2005/bad-uses-of-the-at-operator/)

#### Update:

***In your example***, it is used before the variable name to avoid the `E_NOTICE` error there. If in the `$_POST` array, the `hn` key is not set; it will throw an `E_NOTICE` message, but `@` is used there to avoid that `E_NOTICE`.

Note that you can also put this line on top of your script to avoid an `E_NOTICE` error:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: But it is used before a variable name not a function.

Comment: if `hn` is not set in $_POST, it will throw a notice (`Notice: undefined index...`). `@` will suppress that notice. But using `@` is just wrong.

Comment: Understand now. Thank you Sarfaraz. Hope your people could put the flood behind them soon.

Comment: "PHP6 Note" —— that makes **no** sense.

Comment: Something that others forgot to mention is that besides ignoring the NOTICE, the variable will be set to `NULL`.

Answer (score 11):

It won't throw a warning if $_POST['hn'] is not set.

Answer (score 7):

All that means is that, if $_POST['hn'] is not defined, then instead of throwing an error or warning, PHP will just assign NULL to $hn.

Answer (score 3):

It suppresses warnings if $_POST['something'] is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering 11 years later for completeness regarding modern php.

Since php 7.0, the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) is a more straightforward alternative to silencing warnings in that case. The `??` operator was designed (among other things) for that purpose.

Without `@`, a warning is shown:

```
$ php -r 'var_dump($_POST["hn"]);'
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "hn" in Command line code on line 1
NULL
```

The output with silencing warnings (`@`):

```
$ php -r 'var_dump(@$_POST["hn"]);'
NULL
```

Obtaining the same result with the modern null coalescing operator (`??`):

```
$ php -r 'var_dump($_POST["hn"] ?? null);'
NULL
```